# Firebase storage failing silently?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get the download url for multiple images, then trigger a change in my app. But... if one of those images doesn't exist for whatever reason, everything fails silently.

Here's the code:

```
const promises = [];

snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  const child = childSnapshot.val();
  const promise = firebase.storage()
    .ref(child.songImagePath)
    .getDownloadURL()
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('caught', err);
      return "";
    })
    .then(imageURL => {
      return imageURL;
    });

  promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('caught', err);
  })
  .then(urls => {
    ...do something with urls array
  });
```

I'm using `child.songImagePath` in my database to store the image's location in storage. If ALL paths for ALL images have images, everything works perfectly.

BUT if an upload went awry or for some reason there's no image in the storage location, it fails silently. None of my `catch`es fire. And `Promise.all` is never resolved.

What's going on here? Is there a way to check for a file's existence before calling `getDownloadURL`?

EDIT: As @mjr points out, in the documentation they've formatted their error callback slightly differently than I have. This also seems to never fire an error, though:

```
.then(
    imageURL => {
        return imageURL;
    },
    err => {
        console.log('caught', err);
        return "";
    }
);
```

Comment: [The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) have a different way of formatting the error catching from how you've done it here. I would try this way and see what happens

Comment: I noticed that. Seems also not to throw the error callback. I'll edit the question to show.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `push`ing elements to an array from within a `forEach`.

Comment: Yeah, would be nice. But that snapshot isn't an array, it's a firebase snapshot, so no map function. But I do agree it would be nice if they added one.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Storage JS dev here.

I ran your code with minor changes[1] in Chrome and React Native, and didn't see that behavior.

I see Promise.all always resolving (never failing), with an empty string in the array for invalid files. This is because your `.catch` handler for `getDownloadURL` returns an empty string.

For further troubleshooting, it would be useful to know:

- version of the firebase JS library you are using
- the browser/environment and version
- network logs, for example from the network panel in Chrome's dev tools, or similar for other browsers

The [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) Google Group tends to be a better place for open-ended troubleshooting with more back-and-forth.

[1] For reference, here's my code:

```
const promises = [];

// Swap out the array to test different scenarios

// None of the files exist.
//const arr = ['nofile1', 'nofile2', 'nofile3'];

// All of the files exist.
const arr = ['legitfile1', 'legitfile2', 'legitfile3'];

// Some, but not all, of the files exist.
//const arr = ['legitfile1', 'nofile2', 'nofile3'];

arr.forEach(val => {
  const promise = firebase.storage()
    .ref(val)
    .getDownloadURL()
    .catch(err => {
      // This runs for nonexistent files
      console.log('caught', err);
      return "";
    })
    .then(imageURL => {
      // This runs for existing files
      return imageURL;
    });

  promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .catch(err => {
    // This never runs
    console.log('caught', err);
  })
  .then(urls => {
    // This always runs
    console.log('urls', urls);
  });
```